# How to Remove Newline symbols Produced by some Field of Django Custom Form in Template?

Tags: python, django

Custom Form:

```
CALLMODE_CHOICES = ( 
    (1,'a'), 
    (2,'b'), 
    (3,'c'), 
) 
class EcmNoneTelForm(forms.Form): 
    callmode = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CALLMODE_CHOICES, required=False)
```

Template:

```
{{form.callmode}}
```

Each line has newline:

```
<select name="callmode" id="id_callmode"> 
<option value="1">a</option> 
<option value="2">b</option> 
<option value="3">c</option> 
</select>
```

I wanna all content to be displayed in a row, because I wanna combine {{form.callmode}} with some other string in js script:

```
var str = "<form>" + "{{form.callmode}}" + "</form>";
```

Comment: you want radio select or drop down? Drop down cannot be of single line.

Comment: @Rohan I think he meant the generated HTML, but I am not really certain

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you meant you want the generated HTML to have no newline, I think you can do that with the [`spaceless`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#spaceless) template tag:

```
{% spaceless %}
    <p>
        <a href="foo/">Foo</a>
    </p>
{% endspaceless %}
```

This example would return this HTML:

```
<p><a href="foo/">Foo</a></p>
```

Comment: This works flawlessly! Very useful for embedding multi-line Django HTML bits into javascript.